# Run Python script in GCP Dataflow SDK 2.25.0 - Error message from worker: SDK claims to have processed xxxx but should have processed yyyy elements

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I run my script and is working but sometimes i have a ERROR:
Error message from worker: SDK claims to have processed xxxx but should have processed yyyy elements.

If job not raise no more than 4 error then job is OK - grenn, but i have sometimes 5-6 error in this text and job get status failed. But code is the same. What may be the issue on this error?

Where can I look for the cause?
Of course, I increased the number of starting workers and the type of machine, but the error is generated quite randomly ...

Best regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error.  The behavior around 4 failures is expected; Dataflow will fail a job once a single work item has failed 4 times.

Comment: @legard4d, Can you extend the error trace from the affected worker as was suggested?